# Joint distribution from differential equations

Tags: probability, difference-equations, expectations

I have the following problem -

Z is a random variable which can take any real value in the range [0,1]

a and b are independent variables drawn from uniform distribution in the interval [0,1].

Z is a function of a and b - Z(a, b)

I have differential equation for $\frac{dZ(a, b)}{da}$ and $\frac{dZ(a, b)}{db}$. I computed partial Z(a, b) (partial because they just reflect change in Z with respect to one variable). Let's denote them by $Z_{a}(a, b) $ and $Z_{b}(a, b) $

I have to find complete Z(a, b)

Will it be -

Z(a, b) =  $Z_{a}(a, b) $*$Z_{b}(a, b) $ since a and b are independent

Or

Z(a,b) = prob(a)* $Z_{a}(a, b) $ + prob(b)*  $Z_{b}(a, b) $

I am confused. Any clarification will be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify: it is not possible to write in turn $Z(a), Z(b), Z(a,b)$. Is there any difference between these functions? If yes, please give their definitions and use different notations for different functions.

Comment: @Bertrand thanks for the reply. Basically, I denoted Z(a) because I computed it from differential equation $\frac{dZ(a, b)}{da}$. Z is still a function of both a and b. Is that incorrect way to denote?

Comment: So, let me explain my problem. I recovered Z(a, b) from two differential equation. But overall Z(a, b) will be an expectation computed from combining the two. How should the combination be is my question. Hope that clarifies

Comment: cross posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521484/finding-joint-distribution-from-marginal-distribution

Answer (score 1):

From the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) it follows that the relationship between a function and its partial derivative is given by:
$$ Z(a,b)= \int_0^a \frac{\partial Z}{\partial a}(x,b) dx + Z(0,b), $$
and similarly for the partial derivative of $Z$ wrt $b$.

Comment: I couldn't understand the answer. What are you trying to do here and what is Z(0,b). Isn't this just getting Z(a, b) from individual differential equation. I have already done that. My question is how to combine the two Z(a, b) that I got.